# Python Pandas: add column based on complicated if statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am working on analyzing customer return behavior and am working with the following dataframe df:

```
Customer_ID | Order | Store_ID | Date      | Item_ID | Count_of_units | Event_Return_Flag
ABC           123     1          23052016      A          -1               Y
ABC           345     1          23052016      B           1               0
ABC           567     1          24052016      C          -1               0
```

I need to add another column to find customers who returned during the event (Event_Return_Flag=Y) and bought something in the same day and store.

In other words, I wanted to add a flag df['target'] with the following if logic:

- same Customer_ID, Store_ID, Date as a record with Event_Return_Flag=Y
- but different Item_ID then the record with Event_Return_Flag=Y
- Count_of_units > 0

I don't know how to accomplish this in python pandas.

I was thinking of creating a key by concatenating Customer_ID, Store_ID and Date; then spliting the file by Event_Return_flag and using an isin statement, something like this:

```
df['key']=df['Customer_ID']+'_'+df['Store_ID']+'_'+df['Date'].apply(str)
df_1 = df.loc[df['Event_Return_Flag'] == 'Y']
df_2 = df.loc[df['Event_Return_Flag'] == '0']
df_3 = df2.loc[df['Count_of_units'] > 0]
df3['target'] = np.where(df3['key'].isin(df1['key']), 'Y', 0)
```

This approach seems qutie wrong, but I couldn't come up with something better. I get this error message for the last line with np.where:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I tried something down this line, but couldn't figure out how to match rows based on column Event_Return_Flag

```
df['target'] = (np.where((df.Item_Units_S > 0)&(df.groupby(['key','Item_ID']).Event_Return_flag.transform('nunique') > 1), 'Y', ''))
```